# How to configure Magento 2 to have personal/private develpment extensions just for myself

Tags: magento2, module, composer, git

I have several development tools which I personally use like:

- https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints
- https://github.com/mage2tv/magento-cache-clean

Is it possible to somehow configure and use it for myself? Other team members are not using it.

**The specific issues:**

- app/etc/config.php is in the repo, I cannot commit it
- composer.json and composer.lock are in the repo, I cannot commit it

**I would like to use both modules and enable them without changing any repo files. Would that be possible?**

Answer (score 0):

for https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints
you should add it to app/code
then add the module path to .gitignore for further added by mistake

https://github.com/mage2tv/magento-cache-clean
You can put it in dev folder
also add to .gitignore
this module seems can be ran by access directly like this
dev/{module-path}/bin/cache-clean.js
(not sure about the 2nd module but you can try)

Comment: Thanks. I can try the second suggestion. For the first suggestion; i already did this. But is still needs a line in app/etc/config.php to enable it. Is it possible to bypass this?

Comment: Humm, impossible as I know

Answer (score 0):

- Add the plugins to the app/code folder
- Run bin/console setup:upgrade
- Your local app/etc/config.php file will be changed, but it will not
  influence the one on the server and you won't need to commit it, so
  just keep it changed locally